# Trigger Tekton pipeline from Bitbucket webhook

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, tekton

In one of our project we have to integrate Bitbucket webhook with Tekton pipeline that means whenever developer commits any changes to Bitbucket repository, Tekton pipeline is triggered and will perform several steps to build.

Earlier we have used GitHub webhook with Tekton and it was working fine.
For Bitbucket webhook, we are getting below error:

> failed to replace JSONPath value for param pusher-name: $(body.actor.name): name is not found".

I checked the payload coming from Bitbucket webhook and found there is no such field name.

I used **bitbucket-push** cluster trigger binding plugin.

Can anyone help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tekton triggers and event listener](https://tekton.dev/docs/triggers/)  for that.

Answer (score 0):

With BitBucket, the author name should be somewhere in the actor.username, actor.display_name or actor.nickname

Here's a [sample bitbucket push payload](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/52edc692ea6876f6409f93d1d2b1e175)

You may have other errors. Switching from one git provider to another, you may have to re-do your interceptors, triggertemplates, ...

Meanwhile, it's unclear what you refer to, by "I used butbucket-push cluster trigger ...". Where did you find this? Checking [Tekton Triggers samples](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/tree/main/examples/v1beta1/bitbucket), there's no author.name. Sounds like your issue relates to GitHub-specific configurations.